# Date format issue for Teradata input parakeets

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata

I am trying to give data format in teradata procedure for my input parameters.

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE UDMTOOL_STG_USER.TDPRC_SALES_ESL_INSERT_GLOBAL_APPLE_BRAND_QUERIES 
(
    IN  LV_COUNTRY_CD               VARCHAR(100),
    IN  LV_SEARCHED_KEYWORD_VAL     VARCHAR(300) CHARACTER SET UNICODE,
    IN  LV_SEARCHED_KEYWORD_VAL_ENG VARCHAR(300),
    IN  LV_EFFECTIVE_START_DT       DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    IN  LV_EFFECTIVE_END_DT         DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD', 
    IN  LV_BRAND_NAME               VARCHAR(100),
    IN  LV_INSERT_TS                VARCHAR(19),
    IN  LV_UPDATED_ON               VARCHAR(19),
    IN  LV_UPDATED_BY               VARCHAR(100),
    IN  LN_REQUEST_ID               INTEGER,
    OUT LV_OUT_STATUS               VARCHAR(100) 
)
```

but when I deploy this procedure getting as this error

```
SPL1076:E(L20), The right parenthesis in parameter declaration is missing.
SPL1048:E(L20), Unexpected text ';' in place of SPL statement.
```

please tell me anything wrong here

Comment: FORMAT is simply not supported for SP parameters.

Comment: Snowflake, Oracle or Teradata?

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional hint:

Be careful which session mode you use (ANSI or Teradata) when compiling the Stored Procedure, especially when you cast the date to a string somewhere in the SP.